# Error #1452, foreign key constraint failure

Tags: mysql, sql

I get the following SQL error, please can you tell me what is the problem with this statement?

```
ALTER TABLE `patients` ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Medecin`) REFERENCES `medecin`(`ID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

MySQL answer:

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`dentaire`.`#sql-744_723`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-744_723_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Medecin`) REFERENCES `medecin` (`ID`))

Answer (score 1):

Welcome s_Akashi

This site is for English speaking people, so please asked your question in English. I'm not sure if there is a French speaking stackoverflow site yet, but there are definitely in Spanish and Portuguese (es.stackoverflow.com and pt.stackoverflow.com) if these languages fit you better. I did adjusted the question, if it passes the review, it should be fine now.

To answer your question: You try to add a relationship between the foreign key patients.ID_Medecin and medecin.ID, but there is at least one entry in the patients table that has an ID_Medecin that does not exist and needs to be corrected first.

You can find these with a LEFT OUTER JOIN query (I usually work with Microsoft SQL Server, so I'm not sure if this syntax is 100% correct):

```
SELECT * FROM patients LEFT OUTER JOIN medecin ON patients.ID_Medecin = medecin.ID WHERE medecin.ID IS NULL
```